# Accessing Google Drive (OAuth) on Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have an Android application (made with HTML, CSS, JS). With Phonegap I export the signing application. I obtain the file .keystore and the .apk

I Create google account on Google Console API -> Installed application -> Android. I generate a client_id with the certificate SHA-1 in order to authenticate my application.

In my application, running .apk when I want to log in Google Drive, I can't. I get this error:

> "Invalid Parameter value for origin: Missing Authority: file://"

What have I done wrong?